# How can I download my sqlite database from my Android app without ROOT?

Tags: android, adb

I'm trying to download my sqlite database so that I can review it's contents (*our app does online offline sync, and I'm trying to ensure it's only pulling down what it's supposed to from the API*).

I'm trying to use `adb pull /data/data/com.mycompany.myapp/files/db.sqlite3` but I keep getting permission denied.

I've tried logging in via shell and copying it to the SD card, but I get permission denied there as well (and I don't want to add SDCard access in my Manifest).

```
$ adb shell
$ run-as com.mycompany.myapp
$ cd files
$ cp db.sqlite3 /mnt/sdcard/db.sqlite3
$ PERMISSION DENIED
```

**Without ROOT permission**, how do I download my sqlite file from my android device to a location that will allow me access?

Answer (score 3):

Downloading is (as you see) quite tricky, but not impossible.

Here's the steps to grab the file and move it to your local machine.
*note: I'm on Windows, but this can be done on other devices as long as you know your local paths.*

```
$ adb shell                         // enter into shell
$ run-as [com.mycompany.myapp]      // log in as your app
$ cd [files]                        // navigate to the path of the file you need access to.
$ chmod 0644 [db.sqlite3]           // DANGEROUS: change the permissions of said file allow you access via adb pull
$ {ctrc} + {c}                      // Exit Shell
$ adb pull [/data/data/com.mycompany.myapp/files/db.sqlite3] [c:\db.sqlite3] // pull the file to your local machine.
```

From there, you can navigate to your output directory and access the file.

> **note**: *anything in [square braces] is a variable that you will fill with your own variables.*
>   **note**: *`{ctrl} + {c}` is in PowerShell on Windows, other platforms can be different.*

I've also created a simple Powershell script that does this automatically.

```
$appName = 'com.mycompany.myapp'
$dbName  = 'db'

adb shell "run-as $appName chmod 644 /data/data/$appName/files/$dbName"
adb pull "/data/data/$appName/files/$dbName" "./$dbName.sqlite3"
Invoke-Item ".\$dbName.sqlite3"
```

Comment: Don't use 0777.  At most use 0644.

Comment: @ChrisStratton changed.